# Is this (del.bat) malware or a prank?

Tags: windows-10, virus, malware

Yesterday, I discovered the following batch file running in my SysWOW64 folder:

```
@Echo Off
cd /d C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
:Start
del svchost.exe
If Exist svchost.exe Goto Start
del %0
```

I discovered it when I opened task manager, because I was losing battery like crazy. I have no idea how it started running, because there were no scheduled tasks for it, no services, startup etc., and it was running without a visible window (just `cmd.exe`)

Unfortunately, I killed it in a hurry, since it was maxing out resources, so I didn't catch the arguments, which would have helped make more sense from this. Has anyone experienced this before? I tried running the file through [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/c2848670d14ae833e889025ac195dc19e297a5377c6b45ab3c18f6ea86e7305a/detection), which claims it is totally safe. Or is this a prank or something?

P.S. running Windows 10, fully updated. Malwarebytes doesn't detect anything.

Edit: Some more research brought me to a DDos malware [Xuhuan](https://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/malware/default.aspx?id=140912), but I haven't got the registry keys and other files mentioned my McAffe, as well as no firewall prompts from `explorer.exe`

Edit 2: Virustotal is filled with positive reports now, so I guess this is no longer an issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what (little) it's worth, Malwarebytes now detects this as Trojan.Agent.Trace (their generic "this is nasty but we don't know what virus it's from" name). I found it on my system, which is a hardwired desktop. I live alone. I have no idea how it got there, so this is all pretty chilling.

Reminds me of the old classic 90s viruses. They weren't out to seal your credit card info or use your computer to mine, they just wanna mess with your windows install.

Comment: This'd be pretty odd if somebody made this fairly recently. Nowadays malware like you've said wants to do anything but destroy the computer. This just gets straight to the point, yet on its own it has no way to spread without some assistance. Who knows... maybe some script kiddie wanted to cause some damage and this happened to be included in various downloads?

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through this one line at at time.

```
@Echo Off
```

The commands of the batch script won't be printed to the console when they are run.

```
cd /d C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
```

The script navigates to the SysWOW64 folder on your `C:\` drive. The `/d` switch makes the script change the current drive to `C:\` should it be different.

```
:Start
```

This is a label which is referred to later.

```
del svchost.exe
```

If `svchost.exe` exists in the current directory, delete it. This does not send it to the Recycle Bin; it is gone forever unless you get lucky with file recovery software. Note that this deletes the `svchost.exe` executable that is used for 32-bit services running on a 64-bit system. `svchost.exe` also resides in your `System32` folder, which on a 64-bit system is used for 64-bit services (while on a 32-bit system it is used for 32-bit services).

```
If Exist svchost.exe Goto Start
```

If svchost.exe still exists for whatever reason, the script will loop back round to the `:Start` label defined earlier, and then it'll try to run `del svchost.exe` again until it has been deleted.

```
del %0
```

Once `svchost.exe` has been deleted, the If statement will not loop back round to the label, and instead run this. Normally, this will make the script delete its own file, however according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849095/does-a-bat-file-know-its-name-and-can-it-delete-itself#comment24574003_3849147) on an SO answer this'll not work as the current path would have changed?

I wouldn't run it if you value your operating system.

As for it draining your battery, I can see it running endlessly if it can't delete `svchost.exe` (lacking elevation, file in use?). In this case, the script would be trying to delete the file hundreds if not thousands of times a second; I can see that <s>thrashing your hard drive</s> exhausting your CPU (thanks Sampo for the correction!), thus draining your battery.

Comment: I understand what the file is doing, but the question is why? +1 for explaining the last line though!

Comment: should not trash hdd as acls should be in ram after first read but it will eat a lot of cpu time

Answer (score -1):

This file is not a virus.
It deletes "svchost.exe" file only, and tries to perform task(delete) if this file still exists.

Comment: `svchost.exe` is Windows Service Host, one of crucial components of Windows. Successfully deleting it would pretend Windows from booting. This script is definitely malicious.

Comment: When did I say it is a virus ;)

Comment: It's indeed malicious, but definitelly not a virus ! By definition a virus is written to duplicate itself. This is not the case here !

Comment: @Ob1lan yup, I never did say it is a virus. The question is whether this is related to some known malware. That said, this answer doesn't exactly help.